# Is there any way to Manipulate gif in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, npm

i am using jimp to manipulate images like below code, is there any other similer thing to manipulate gif?

```
var jimp = require('jimp');

jimp.read('images.png').then(function (image) {

    image.scaleToFit(32, jimp.AUTO, jimp.RESIZE_BEZIER)
   .write('aa.png');

}).catch (function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sharp is another image manipulation package available on node.js.But jimp might be the best out there , i thing you could give sharp a try or stick with jimp!